# GameMaker Studio 2: DnD - How do I change Idle animation to Walking Animation

Tags: game-maker

I have an idle animation into an object. I am able to have it moved to one point, left & right but but the problem is transitioning from Idle to Walking Forward. I did tried step but I realized that it's for animation ticks, and I can't really find any tutorials on it yet.

How do make a smooth animation transition from Idle to Walking?

Comment: I'm not an expert in GameMaker, but it looks like it would be helpful to edit this question to include more details of how you have set up your animations so far, and what specifically you need help solving. Do you not know how to create a transition at all? Or have you created a transition, but it's currently not smooth, or experiencing a flicker? These details can guide what kind of help other users offer you.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. Hopefully my question is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

sprite_index changes the sprite and image_index changes the frame of the sprite

also now setting the speed in the sprite editor for that sprite (default is 15) will set the speed for the transition to the next frame.